# How to read payload in Python?

Tags: python, azure-functions, payload

I have azure function in Azure Function App, which takes the http request with a payload.
I am finding it difficult to read that payload & convert into Python data structure, Although I need that Information to process further.

Payload sample:

```
{"Tables":['Table_Product','Table_Sales'], 
"Cols":{'Table_Product':['ProdId','Prod_Name','Prod_Desc'],'Table_Sales':['ProdId','Prod_Sales','Prod_Qty']}, 
"Rows":{'Prod_Sales':'{'gt':'3000'}'}, 
  
"Function": 
{ 
     "join":"{Type :'default')", 
         "groupby":"{'cols' :('ProdId', 'Prod_Name', 'Prod_Sales')}", 
         "agg":"{ 'Type' : 'Sum','Value' :'prod_sales'}", 
         "sortby":"{'type':'Asc','cols':('prod_sales','b')}",         
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use librabry JSON to parse

```
your_payload = (your payload example)

import json
#string to dictionary or list
dj = json.loads(your_payload) #This will be a dictionary 

#reverse, dictionary to string
payload_string = json.dumps(dj)
```

Comment: Not working for the above example